# Eliminar un intervalo de elementos dentro de un Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist

Estoy recién empezando en el mundo de la programación y de JavaScript. Me tocó intentar resolver el siguiente problema:

> *Dado un array y su respectivo índice, remueve los valores en el rango del índice dado(acortando el array). Por ejemplo, removerRango([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4) debiera devolver [20,30,70].*

Solo he podido conseguir identificar y guardar en una variable los elementos del rango dado, en este caso `(40,50,60)` con el siguiente código:

```js
function cut(x, y, z) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (i = y; i <= z; i++) {
    if (x[i] >= x[y]) {
      resultado.push(x[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(resultado);
  return resultado;
}

d = cut([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4);
console.log(d);
```

Si pueden ayudarme a entender la resolución a este problema, se los agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si recién estás empezando seguro no viste varios de los métodos de *array* que podrian ayudarte. Así que lo continúo con el `for` para no confundirte. Podés recorrer todo el *array* y solo vas a poner en el resultado los índices que no estén en ese rango:

```js
if (!(i >= y && i <= z)) {
  resultado.push(x[i]);
}
```

```js
function cut(x, y, z) {
  resultado = [];

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!(i >= y && i <= z)) {
      resultado.push(x[i]);
    }
  }

  return resultado;
}

const result = cut([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias. Utilicé tú código, eso si me costó entenderlo al principio ajjajajaja. Tendré que seguir estudiando los booleanos y los métodos de array. Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

> Aunque ya hay varias respuestas y una aceptada, quiero aprovechar esta oportunidad para dar un aporte sobre este tema.

Tomando como punto de partida lo que sigue, cito:

> *Dado un array y su respectivo índice, remueve los valores en el rango del índice dado (acortando el array). Por ejemplo, **removerRango([20,30,40,50,60,70],2,4)** debiera devolver **[20,30,70]**.*

Esto sería una posible solución:

```js
const x = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];

const removerRango = (array, desde, hasta) => {
  let cantidad = --hasta;
  array.splice(desde, cantidad);
}

// Modificar eliminando elementos del rango elegido:
removerRango(x, 2, 4);

// Ver el array modificado
console.log(x);
```

Sin embargo, para comprender bien la solución anterior vamos a entender lo que es un `Array`.

De acuerdo a la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(inform%C3%A1tica)), cito:

> En programación, se le denomina vector, formación, matriz (en inglés array, del cual surge la mala traducción arreglo),1​ a una zona de almacenamiento contiguo que contiene una serie de elementos del mismo tipo, los elementos de la matriz.2​ Desde el punto de vista lógico una matriz se puede ver como un conjunto de elementos ordenados en fila (o filas y columnas si tuviera dos dimensiones).

Ahora imagínese un `Array` como si fuese un *casillero con varias casillas* donde se guardan las cosas.

Bien, representaremos al `Array` numérico de la siguiente manera:

[image]

Donde los números grandes son los elementos del `Array` y los números pequeños, los índices.

Lo que hace el método **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)** es modificar el `Array`. El funcionamiento, básicamente es éste:

```js
array.splice( empezarEn, eliminarCantidadDeElementos, ... );
```

Donde **`empezarEn`** es el indice del `Array` que vamos a modificar y desde donde queremos empezar a eliminar elementos, **eliminarCantidadDeElementos** la cantidad de elementos a eliminar (valga la redundancia) y los puntos suspensivos (intencionalmente puesto así) representan una cantidad variable de parámetros opcionales. Si **`eliminarCantidadDeElementos`** vale `0`, entonces no se eliminarán elementos del `Array`.

Ahora bien, nos vamos a concentrar en la parte que nos interesa.

Si queremos eliminar:

[image]

```js
const x = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];
x.splice(2, 3);
console.log(x);
```

Con `x.splice(2, 3)` hemos eliminado en el rango `2 - 4` tres (03) elementos:

[image]

Dando como resultado lo siguiente:

[image]

Por lo tanto, cuando definimos una función denominada **removerRango( array, empezarEn, hasta )** al parámetro **hasta** debemos restarle uno para que dé la cantidad de elementos que queremos eliminar:

```js
const x = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];
const removerRango = ( array, empezarEn, hasta ) => {
    let paraEliminarCantidad = --hasta;
    array.splice(empezarEn, paraEliminarCantidad);
}

removerRango(x, 2, 4);
console.log( x );
```

### Actualización

Los pasos anteriores modifican directamente el *array*. Sin embargo, si desea devolver una copia sin modificar el original podríamos definirlo así:

```js
const removerRango = (array, desde, hasta) => {
  return array.filter((numero, indice) => {
    return !(indice >= desde && indice <= hasta);
  });
};

const datos = removerRango([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4);

console.log(datos);
```

De manera que al ejecutar nuestra función `removerRango()`:

```js
const datos = removerRango(array, desde, hasta);
```

Devuelva un nuevo *array* en la variable que hemos denominado `datos` con los valores indicados (`[20,30,70]`) que visualizaremos en la consola:

```js
console.log(datos); // [20, 30, 70];
```

El funcionamiento de nuestra función que hemos modificado este:

En la línea:

```js
return array.filter((numero, indice) => {
  return !(indice >= desde && indice <= hasta);
});
```

Nuestra función devolverá un *array* de elementos que no pertenezcan al rango `2 - 4`, es decir:

```js
return !(indice >= desde && indice <= hasta);
```

Donde los elementos que se encuentran en el `indice` en un rango `desde` - `hasta` serán ignorados.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por dedicar tiempo a explicar con mayor detalle. Me es de gran utilidad para profundizar. Saludos!

Comment: Oportuna y aguda observación, colega. Pero recomiendo que no se den soluciones que modifiquen el array, porque estaba respondiendo la pregunta y me encontré con que tenía cada vez menos elementos :D

Comment: Era un chiste :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function cut(x, y, z)
{
   resultado = [];

   for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
   {
      if(i < x || i > z)
      {
         resultado.push(x[i]);
      }
   }

   return resultado;
}
```

Atendiendo a lo que ya tienes hecho te propongo lo siguiente, recorro el arreglo desde la primera posición hasta la última, y pregunto si el índice del **ciclo for** está fuera del intervalo del arreglo original que no quiero copiar, de ser cierto pues copio este elemento del arreglo original al arreglo nuevo, de no ser cierto pues no copio nada al nuevo arreglo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero lamentablemente me arroja un array vacío.

Comment: @FranciscoCastillo ya arreglé el error, me equivoqué de operador lógico, puse && y debe ser ||, que es el or

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que puedes utilizar ES6 (pero si estás aprendiendo, entiendo que lo haces ya sobre la última versión ampliamente soportada en los *major browsers*), te dejo la siguiente propuesta:

```
function cut(inputArray, start, end) {
  const tempArray = [...inputArray];
  tempArray.splice(start, end - start + 1);
  return tempArray;
}
```

Ejemplo reproducible:

```js
function cut(inputArray, start, end) {
  const tempArray = [...inputArray];
  tempArray.splice(start, end - start + 1);
  return tempArray;
}

console.log('Resultado: ', cut([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4));
```

Habría que hacer alguna comprobación adicional de los parámetros de entrada de la función (índices válidos, positivos, start < end, etc. Pero como primera aproximación podría valer.

Te dejo [este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) para consultar más sobre la función del propio estándar (splice), que es muy potente y permite escribir un código más sencillo, compacto y legible.

Cualquier duda puedes preguntar en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias, te haré caso en investigar y profundizar la función splice, la había leído antes pero aún cuesta entenderla del todo bien. Saludos!