# Funcionamiento de método splice con max

Tags: javascript, math

Tengo un dilema con esta línea de código:

```js
let numero = [11, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12];
console.log(numero.splice(Math.min.apply(null, numero), 1));
console.log(numero);
```

Esta línea de código debería eliminar el numero `5` que es el **menor del array**, pero **me elimina el `12`**. He intentado de diferentes formas, pero no logro dar con la solución para eliminar el `5`.

Answer (score 4):

> **Importante:** lea los comentarios que se encuentran en el código. Allí se documenta lo que hace cada línea.

### Esta es la razón

Lo que ocurre con:

```js
Math.min.apply(null, numeros);
```

Es que devuelve el número más pequeño (tal y como lo has planteado) y no su índice. Entonces, para poder eliminar el número que está devolviendo debemos conocer primero su índice (valga la redundancia).

Entonces, esta es la forma en el que lo podemos averiguar:

```js
numeros.indexOf( Math.min.apply(null, numeros) );
```

Una vez, que ya conocemos su **índice** podemos eliminarla del array, es decir:

```js
// Nuestro array de números:
const numeros = [11,5,7,9,10,12];

// Obtenemos su índice:
let indice = numeros.indexOf( Math.min.apply(null, numeros));

// Eliminamos del array el número que se encuentra en 
// el índice indicado, es decir, el 5:
numeros.splice( indice, 1 );

// Mostramos los resultados en la consola:
console.log( numeros );
```

> Puede visitar *[Eliminar un intervalo de elementos dentro de un Array Javascript (?)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418085/eliminar-un-intervalo-de-elementos-dentro-de-un-array-javascript/418285#418285)*. Allí explico un poco el funcionamiento del método `splice` (se incluye ejemplo gráfico). También puede consultar [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para profundizar un poco más sobre el tema.

Comment: tiene toda la razón, estaba tan cansado que no pensé en eso, muchas gracias, gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error esta en que debes de buscar su índice y no el valor en sí. Para esto puedes usar el método [.indexOf ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
let numero = [11, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let index = numero.indexOf(Math.min(...numero));
console.log(numero.splice(index, 1));
console.log(numero)
```

Comment: Hola @John, acá estás mostrando el número que elimina. Agrega otra línea, es decir,  un `console.log( numero )` para que se muestre el `Array` sin el `5`. Me reservo `+1` a la espera de que completes tu edición.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Es correcto, ya lo corrijo en mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Trata de corregir el `Math.min.apply`, solo le añade esa una P mas al `apply`, así lo hice yo y me funcionó, espero te sea de ayuda

Resultado:

```javascript
console.log(numero.splice(Math.min.apply(null, numero), 1));
```