# Hacer pop() de array según índice

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy haciendo un *eCommerce* con JavaScript y tengo unos productos, los cuales, pueden ser agregados al carrito.

Cuando apreto el botón de **agregar al carrito** se ejecuta la función `AgregarCarrito()`, y la *info* del producto se guarda en un *array* llamado `aCarrito` para ser luego mostrada en la seccion de carrito del *eCommerce*.

En esta misma hay un botón para eliminar el producto, pero el problema es que al apretarlo y ejecutando el método `pop()` me elimina el último elemento o producto agregado al *array*.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me elimine el producto que deseo al apretar eliminar?

Aquí les va el código:

Fragmento HTML:

```html
<div id="carrito_pagina" data-role="page">
  <header>
    <a href="#home_pagina" class="flecha">atras</a>
    <div class="header_block">
      <h1>Carrito</h1>
      <p>0 productos</p>
    </div>
    <div class="vaciar">
      vaciar
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="no_productos">
    <p>Todavía no hay productos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll_vertical2">
    <section id="carrito">
      <ul class="padding">
        <!-- Productos del carrito dinámicos -->
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="cont_btn">
    <div class="cont_btn_texto">
      <p>0 productos</p>
      <p>Total:$0</p>
    </div>
    <a class="button">Checkout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fragmento JavaScript:

```js
let aCarrito = [];

let aRelojes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg`,
    nombre: "Oyster Perpetual 41",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 6400,
    descripcion:
      "La estética de los modelos Oyster Perpetual los diferencia de los demás como símbolos de estilo clásico y universal. Respetando la línea de los orígenes pioneros de Rolex, encarnan la forma y función atemporales.",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg`,
    nombre: "Lady Datejust",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 41250,
    descripcion:
      "Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster de 28 mm, coronada con un biselengastado de diamantes. Arquetipo del clásico femenino de Rolex, el Lady‑Datejust pertenece a la línea del Datejust, modelo emblemático que impuso su estilo y sus prestaciones relojeras.",
  },
  {
    estado: "Nuevo",
    id: 3,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/datejust_41.jpg`,
    nombre: "Datejust 41",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 14300,
    descripcion:
      "Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster 41 mm, coronada con un bisel estriado. En lo referente a la estética, el Datejust ha conservado con el paso de los años los códigos inmutables que aún hoy en día hacen de él, en su versión tradicional, uno de los relojes más reconocidos y reconocibles.",
  },
  {
    estado: "Nuevo",
    id: 4,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/pearl_master_39.jpg`,
    nombre: "Pearlmaster 39",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 32500,
    descripcion:
      "El Pearlmaster ocupa un lugar especial en la colección Oyster, con metales y piedras preciosos, representa la cima de la excelencia.Las esferas pavé de diamantes son una combinación mágica de luces que embellece el reloj y hechiza a quien lo lleva. Los engastadores modelan los metales preciosos para preparar el espacio donde alojarán perfectamente cada piedra preciosa de forma manual.",
  },
  {
    estado: "Nuevo",
    id: 5,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/explorer_ii.jpg`,
    nombre: "Explorer II",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 9050,
    descripcion:
      "Está equipado con una visualización adicional de 24 horas; una aguja dedicada da vuelta a la esfera en 24 horas en lugar de las usuales 12, apuntando a un bisel fijo con graduaciones de 24 horas. Esta función permite a quienes lo llevan distinguir las horas del día de las de la noche, una característica que resulta esencial para quienes se adentran en medios ambientes donde reina la oscuridad —como las profundidades de las cuevas o donde el sol nunca se pone— como en las regiones polares durante el verano.",
  },
  {
    estado: "Tendencias",
    id: 6,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/datejust_31.jpg`,
    nombre: "Datejust 31",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 17300,
    descripcion:
      "Su esfera presenta VI grande engastado con diamantes. Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster 31 mm, coronada con un bisel engastado de diamantes. En lo referente a la estética, el Datejust ha conservado con el paso de los años los códigos inmutables que aún hoy en día hacen de él, en su versión tradicional, uno de los relojes más reconocidos y reconocibles.",
  },
  {
    estado: "Tendencias",
    id: 7,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/sky_dweller.jpg`,
    nombre: "Sky Dweller",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 43250,
    descripcion:
      "Este inconfundible reloj se caracteriza por la visualización del doble huso horario en un disco excéntrico en la esfera. Además, su innovador sistema para ajustar las funciones, con ayuda del bisel giratorio Ring Command, es único de Rolex. ",
  },

  {
    estado: "Tendencias",
    id: 8,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_31.jpg`,
    nombre: "Oyster Perpetual 31",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 5650,
    descripcion:
      "La estética de los modelos Oyster Perpetual los diferencia de los demás como símbolos de estilo clásico y universal. Respetando la línea de los orígenes pioneros de Rolex, encarnan la forma y función atemporales.",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/submariner.jpg`,
    nombre: "Submariner",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 8800,
    descripcion:
      "Presenta un bisel giratorio unidireccional con disco Cerachrom y brazalete Oyster con elementos macizos. La última generación de Submariner y Submariner Date permanece fiel al modelo original lanzado en 1953. El Submariner supuso un hito en la historia de la relojería y se convirtió en el reloj de buceo por excelencia.",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/day_date_36.jpg`,
    nombre: "Day Date 36",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 22800,
    descripcion:
      "Su esfera presenta Indicadores en oro de 18 quilates engastados de 32 diamantes, números romanos VI y IX en oro de 18 quilates engastados de 24 diamantes. El Day‑Date fue el primer reloj en indicar el día de la semana con todas las letras cuando se presentó por primera vez en 1956.",
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/day_date_40.jpg`,
    nombre: "Day Date 40",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 39500,
    descripcion:
      "El Day‑Date fue el primer reloj en indicar el día de la semana con todas las letras cuando se presentó por primera vez en 1956.El bisel estriado de Rolex es una marca de distinción. En un principio, el diseño estriado del bisel Oyster tenía una función específica: servía para atornillar el bisel a la caja garantizando la hermeticidad del reloj.",
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/date_34.jpg`,
    nombre: "Date 34",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 9200,
    descripcion:
      "Su esfera presenta diamantes con engaste chatón de oro de 18 quilates. Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster 34 mm, coronada con un bisel estriado. En lo referente a la estética, el Datejust ha conservado con el paso de los años los códigos inmutables que aún hoy en día hacen de él, en su versión tradicional, uno de los relojes más reconocidos y reconocibles.",
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/cosmograph_daytona.jpg`,
    nombre: "Cosmograph Daytona",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 18800,
    descripcion:
      "Este cronógrafo se creó para ser la mejor herramienta de cronometraje de los pilotos de resistencia. Más de 50 años después de su creación, el Cosmograph Daytona no ha dejado de trascender el tiempo para alcanzar en la actualidad un estatus sin igual en el firmamento de los cronógrafos deportivos.",
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    marca: "Rolex",
    imagen: `./img/rolex/yacht_master_40.jpg`,
    nombre: "Yacht Master 40",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 18800,
    descripcion:
      "Este modelo presenta una esfera color negro intenso y un bisel giratorio bidireccional graduado 60 minutos con disco Cerachrom negro mate de cerámica, números y graduaciones pulidos en relieve. Las características herméticas y robustas de este modelo lo convierten en el reloj ideal para los deportes acuáticos y la navegación en particular.",
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    marca: "Longines",
    imagen: `./img/longines/primaluna.jpg`,
    nombre: "Primaluna",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 2610,
    descripcion:
      "Aunque la marca Longines sea conocida de sobra por su oferta de modelos tanto para hombre como para mujer, su colección Longines PrimaLuna se perfila desde 2009 como exclusivamente femenina. Su característica caja se inspira en la luna y su poesía, como su nombre indica. Sus esferas plateadas o nacaradas engastadas de diamantes recuerdan el brillo del astro nocturno. Estos modelos cobran vida gracias a los movimientos de cuarzo o automáticos según su elección, en una versión con 3 agujas/fecha o con indicador de las fases... ¡de la luna!",
  },
  {
    estado: "Tendencias",
    id: 16,
    marca: "Longines",
    imagen: `./img/longines/spirit.jpg`,
    nombre: "Spirit",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 2040,
    descripcion:
      "La colección Longines Spirit está diseñada con el mismo patrón que los relojes que han acompañado a pioneros legendarios que confiaron en los instrumentos Longines en la conquista de tierra, mar y aire. Aviadores y exploradores de leyenda como Amelia Earhart, Paul-Emile Victor, Elinor Smith y Howard Hughes confiaron en la marca del reloj de arena alado para sus increíbles viajes. Hoy, Longines presenta estos nuevos modelos que hacen de testimonio de su espíritu pionero. Un homenaje vibrante a aquellos hombres y mujeres excepcionales que han marcado la historia gracias a un récord, una hazaña, una ola de coraje, y llevan a las nuevas generaciones a superarse. Todos los modelos de la colección Longines Spirit cuentan con una tecnología de vanguardia, que ofrece un movimiento extremadamente preciso y con certificado cronómetro.",
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    marca: "Longines",
    imagen: `./img/longines/grand_classique.jpg`,
    nombre: "Grand Classique",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 1540,
    descripcion:
      "Presentada en 1992, La Grande Classique de Longines ha contribuido con creces a forjar el renombre de la casa del reloj de arena alado. Símbolo de la elegancia clásica y del refinamiento atemporal de Longines, esta línea se caracteriza por su finísimo perfil y su rica variedad de estilos. Destinada para un público tanto masculino como femenino, esta emblemática colección se posa sobre las muñecas de aquellos que saben apreciar los valores seguros.",
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    marca: "Longines",
    imagen: `./img/longines/conquest.jpg`,
    nombre: "Conquest",
    categoria: "Hombre",
    precio: 1250,
    descripcion:
      "El Longines Conquest representa la quintaesencia de la elegancia deportiva de la marca. Se ha prestado especial atención a la forma del bisel, de la corona con cabujón y de los eslabones de la pulsera. Sutil unión de prestaciones y elegancia, el Longines Conquest posee todas las características técnicas necesarias para satisfacer las expectativas de los deportistas más exigentes. Sobrio y sofisticado a la vez, este modelo no pasa desapercibido en las fiestas más elegantes y en las tribunas de prestigiosas carreras de caballos.",
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    marca: "Longines",
    imagen: `./img/longines/dolceVita.jpg`,
    nombre: "DolceVita",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 1830,
    descripcion:
      "Desde su creación, la colección Longines DolceVita ilustra a través del mundo la elegancia contemporánea de la maison relojera Longines. Inspirado en la «Dolce Vita», es un himno a la dulzura de vivir. Hoy se abre un nuevo capítulo de esta colección con una interpretación inédita de líneas suavizadas. Estas nuevas variaciones no dejarán de seducir a las mujeres que han convertido el encanto en un estilo de vida.",
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    marca: "Longines",
    imagen: `./img/longines/presence.jpg`,
    nombre: "Présence",
    categoria: "Mujer",
    precio: 1100,
    descripcion:
      "La colección Présence se mantiene fiel a la elegancia clásica y atemporal que caracteriza a la marca relojera suiza Longines. Su caja estructurada con líneas sencillas, gustará por igual tanto a hombres como a mujeres. Adornado con números romanos, su esfera conjuga elegancia con una fácil lectura. Todas estas características se unen para hacer de esta línea una parte esencial de la colección Longines.",
  },
];

function AgregarCarrito() {
  let repetidos = aCarrito.findIndex(
    (item) => item.nombre == this.dataset.nombre
  );
  if (repetidos >= 0) {
    aCarrito[repetidos].cantidad++;

    return;
  }
  aCarrito.push({
    id: this.dataset.id,
    imagen: this.dataset.src,
    nombre: this.dataset.nombre,
    categoria: this.dataset.categoria,
    precio: this.dataset.precio,
    cantidad: this.dataset.cantidad,
  });
  cl(aCarrito);
  //Agregar al carrito
  //Sintaxis literal
  /*
            <ul class="padding">
            <li class="producto_carrito">
                <picture>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </picture>
                <div class="detalles_producto">
                    <h2>Nombre Producto</h2>
                    <p>Categoría</p>
                    <p>$300</p>
                </div>
               
            </li>

        </ul>
*/

  let carritoUl = document.querySelector("#carrito ul");
  let liCarrito = document.createElement("li");
  liCarrito.classList.add("producto_carrito");
  carritoUl.appendChild(liCarrito);

  let pictureCarrito = document.createElement("picture");
  liCarrito.appendChild(pictureCarrito);

  let imgCarrito = document.createElement("img");
  pictureCarrito.appendChild(imgCarrito);
  imgCarrito.src = this.dataset.src;

  let detallesCarrito = document.createElement("div");
  detallesCarrito.classList.add("detalles_producto");
  liCarrito.appendChild(detallesCarrito);

  let nombreCarrito = document.createElement("h2");
  detallesCarrito.appendChild(nombreCarrito);
  nombreCarrito.innerHTML = this.dataset.nombre;

  let categoriaCarrito = document.createElement("p");
  detallesCarrito.appendChild(categoriaCarrito);
  categoriaCarrito.innerHTML = this.dataset.categoria;

  let precioCarrito = document.createElement("p");
  detallesCarrito.appendChild(precioCarrito);
  let precioFinal = this.dataset.precio * this.dataset.cantidad;
  precioCarrito.innerHTML = `$${precioFinal}`;

  let cantidadCarrito = document.createElement("span");
  cantidadCarrito.classList.add("cantidad_unidades");
  liCarrito.appendChild(cantidadCarrito);
  cantidadCarrito.innerHTML = `${this.dataset.cantidad} Uni.`;

  let eliminar = document.createElement("span");
  liCarrito.appendChild(eliminar);
  eliminar.innerHTML = "x";
  eliminar.classList.add("eliminar");
  eliminar.onclick = function () {
    aCarrito.pop();
    aPrecios.pop();
    CantidadDeProductos();
    Total();
    liCarrito.remove();
    liCheckout.remove();
    if (aCarrito.length == 0) {
      location.reload();
    }
    cl(aCarrito);
  };
}
```

Comment: Hola @Michael. Coloca el código HTML faltante a la que se hace referencia desde la función `AgregarCarrito()` para que puedas completar tu pregunta.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. ahi lo he colocado. Si te fijas hay un comentario en el codigo html donde es la carga dinamica de los productos desde js

Comment: Ok. Ya te estoy prepando una respuesta. Ya te la publico ahorita. Estoy tomando lo mínimo necesario.

Answer (score 4):

### Debes utilizar el método splice()

Debes utilizar el método `splice()` en lugar del método `pop()`. El método `pop()` siempre eliminará el último elemento del *array*, mientras que con el método `splice()` puedes eliminar el elemento del *array* en la posición indicada.

> Lee toda la explicación. Le será de mucha ayuda.

Pruebe el siguiente fragmento y después siga leyendo (ejemplo concreto):

```js
const aCarrito = [{
    id: 1,
    imagen: "/ruta/de/imagen.jpeg",
    nombre: "Nombre del producto",
    categoria: "Categoría",
    precio: "30.12 USD",
    cantidad: 30,
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    imagen: "/ruta/de/imagen-02.jpeg",
    nombre: "Nombre del producto | 02",
    categoria: "Categoría",
    precio: "12.15 USD",
    cantidad: 25,
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    imagen: "/ruta/de/imagen-03.jpeg",
    nombre: "Nombre del producto | 03",
    categoria: "Categoría",
    precio: "100.00 USD",
    cantidad: 3,
  },
];

const eliminarProducto = (array, id) => {
  // Utilizamos el método findIndex para encontrar el índice
  // del array de productos:
  let indice = array.findIndex(producto => producto.id === id);

  // Devolverá un array vacío si no encuentra el producto:
  if (indice === -1) return [];

  // Devolverá un array de productos eliminados:
  return array.splice(indice, 1);
};

console.log("Antes de eliminar un producto:");
console.log(aCarrito);

let productoEliminado = eliminarProducto(aCarrito, 3);

console.log("Producto eliminado:");
console.log(productoEliminado);

console.log("Después de eliminar un producto:");
console.log(aCarrito);
```

Esto es, partiendo de la idea de que se definió el producto así:

```js
aCarrito = [
  {
    id: 1,
    imagen: "/ruta/de/imagen.jpeg",
    nombre: "Nombre del producto",
    categoria: "Categoría",
    precio: "30.12 USD",
    cantidad: 30,
  },
];
```

Y que su eliminación pasa por el `id`.

```js
eliminarProducto(aCarrito, id);
```

### Explicación

Se crea la función `eliminarProducto(array, id)` con dos argumentos:

- **`array`:** es el *array* que se desea modificar eliminando de él un objeto (producto).
- **`id`:** es el `id` del producto. El punto de partida que utilizamos para eliminar el objeto (producto) dentro del array. Podría utilizarse cualquier propiedad, pero nos enfocaremos en ella por el momento.

#### Funcionamiento de la función `eliminarProducto()`

En nuestra función tenemos la siguientes líneas:

```js
let indice = array.findIndex((producto) => producto.id === id);
```

Que es la posición del *producto* dentro de nuestro *array* `aCarrito`. Si el objeto no es encontrado el `indice` valdrá `-1`.

Si indice vale -1, devolverá un *array* vacío para indicar que no se ha producido ninguna eliminación del *producto.*

```js
if (indice === -1) return [];
```

Sin embargo, si la posición del producto dentro del *array* ha sido encontrada devolverá un *array* con el objeto eliminado, a la vez, que eliminará el *producto* devuelto de `aCarrito`:

```js
return array.splice(indice, 1);
```

El método `splice` modifica el *array*. Por lo tanto, con él puedes cambiar uno o varios elementos por otros, eliminarlos o agregar nuevos al *array*.

> Si desea ampliar un poco sobre cómo funciona el método `splice` puede consultar [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice). También puede leer [Eliminar un intervalo de elementos dentro de un Array Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418085/eliminar-un-intervalo-de-elementos-dentro-de-un-array-javascript/418285#418285) donde explico con más detalle su funcionamiento.
>
> Si quiere aprender un poco más sobre el método `findIndex` puede consultar [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex)